# Menu items won't get destroyed on rotation - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, rotation, fragment

I've created simple app using two fragments. One is responsible for displaying the scrollview of thumbnails. The other one is displayed only in landscape mode or in other activity after clicking on one of the textviews in first fragment and is showing details of clicked textview. The second fragment also has "share" menu item.

[How the portrait layout should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoFqI.png)

When rotating phone to landscape mode the "share" menu item of the second fragment is displayed correctly in the menu. When rotating the phone back to portrait, the "share" button is still visible even when it should be destroyed.

[Landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQeky.png)

Here the menu should be empty again:

[The wrong menu layout - how it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OulKh.png)

This is how I'm creating share button in second fragment

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        // Also tried menu.clear(), that didn't work either
        if (menu.findItem(R.menu.detail_menu ) == null){
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, menu)
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.item_menu_share){
            Log.i(TAG, "Clicked on share")
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            i.type = "text/plain"
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL")
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, DataProvider.data[identifier]?.address)
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"))
        }else{
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
        return true
    }
```

How do I remove the element from the menu or how do I stop it from being shown even after rotation? I've

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what you're trying to achieve with the check in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`. I presume you have different menu resources for landscape and portrait?

Comment: I don't have any menu resources for portrait. The share button is inflated in the fragment displaying thumbnail detail. The one that is shown in landscape mode on the right. All I want to do is delete the share button when the screen is rotated back to portrait.